# Filter a field with more than two exception criteria in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, exception, autofilter

Is there a way to create an autofilter with more than 2 exceptions without using loop to create an array of items except exceptions?!

Something like a special operator or combination of criteria1 and criteria2 with "Xland" operator.....

Answer (score 0):

If it is only for 2 criteria it is possible like

```
.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= "<>product3", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<>product4"
```

This will remove the **exact match** of `"product3"` and `"product4"` from the filered data. The following will remove all rows that **contain** `"product3"` or `"product4"`:

```
.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= "<>*product3*", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<>*product4*"
```

But if you want to remove more than 2 criteria you would need to loop as you mentioned in your question.

Comment: @SaeedMJ If you read the documentation of the [Range.AutoFilter method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.autofilter) you will see that there are only 2 criteria you can use. So you only have these 2 options (stick with 2 criteria only or use a loop to create an array for the filter). Alternatively to the loop you can add a helper column with a formula that checks all your criteria in the current row and returns `TRUE` or `FALSE` either if all criteria are fulfilled or not. Then you can use the helper column to filter.

Comment: But the helper column only makes sense if the criteria don't change (because you hard code them into the formula). If they change I would prefer the loop.